# Draw spherical coordinates definition in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-3dplot

I want to draw the following image in TikZ that defines the spherical coordinates.

[image]

The result of my efforts so far is in the MWE below. Thanks for any help!

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz, tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}

\tdplotsetmaincoords{75}{125}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\R}{2}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\r}{1.85}

\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords]
\draw[gray, thick, -Stealth] (-2,0,0) -- (5,0,0) node[black, left] {$x$};
\draw[gray, thick, -Stealth] (0,-2,0) -- (0,4,0) node[black, right] {$y$};
\draw[gray, thick, -Stealth] (0,0,-2) -- (0,0,4) node[black, left] {$z$};

\shade[ball color=brown, tdplot_screen_coords, opacity=0.6] (0,0,0) circle [radius=\R];

\fill [brown!67!black, canvas is xz plane at y=0, opacity=0.6] (\R,0) arc [start angle=0, end angle=90, radius=\R] -- (0,\r) arc [start angle=90, end angle=0, radius=\r] -- cycle;
\fill [brown!50, canvas is xz plane at y=0, opacity=0.6] (0,0) -- (\r,0) arc [start angle=0, end angle=90, radius=\r] -- cycle;

\fill [brown!67!black, canvas is xy plane at z=0, opacity=0.6] (\R,0) arc [start angle=0, end angle=90, radius=\R] -- (0,\r) arc [start angle=90, end angle=0, radius=\r] -- cycle;
\fill [brown!50, canvas is xy plane at z=0, opacity=0.6] (0,0) -- (\r,0) arc [start angle=0, end angle=90, radius=\r] -- cycle;

\fill [brown!67!black, canvas is yz plane at x=0, opacity=0.6] (\R,0) arc [start angle=0, end angle=90, radius=\R] -- (0,\r) arc [start angle=90, end angle=0, radius=\r] -- cycle;
\fill [brown!50, canvas is yz plane at x=0, opacity=0.6] (0,0) -- (\r,0) arc [start angle=0, end angle=90, radius=\r] -- cycle;

\fill [blue!67, opacity=0.6] (0,0,-3) -- ({-3*(cos(15))},{-3*(sin(15)},-4) -- ({-3*(cos(15))},{-3*(sin(15))},3) -- (0,0,3) -- cycle;

\draw [thick, -Latex, canvas is xy plane at z=0] (0.5,0) arc [start angle=0, end angle=75, radius=0.5];
\node at (1,0.25,-0.25) {$\theta_0$};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You can see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/586948/draw-spherical-coordinates-definition-in-tikz)

Comment: @minhthien_2016 The link you sent is the link to this question!

Comment: I am sorry about that. It is [here](https://topanswers.xyz/tex?q=1693#a1923)

Comment: Thanks for your help. That is very beautiful. Unfortunately the 3dtools library is not installed on my system. I try to install it and complete the details of the figure. Of course I do not know how to install a new library!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a tricky one, that's for sure. The main difficulties are the cone generatrices, the tangent point between the ellipse in the plane and the sphere, and the order for what you can see and what not. In my solution I used isometric axes, for easier computations, but there is still a lot of trigonometry.

This is what I did:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage    {tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{3d,calc}

\tikzset
{%
  cone_inside/.style={fill=gray!40,,fill opacity=0.75},
  cone_outside/.style={fill=gray!20,fill opacity=0.75},
  sphere_inside/.style={fill=red!40},
  sphere_outside/.style={fill=red!20},
  plane/.style={fill=green!20,fill opacity=0.75}
}

\def\sr{2}    % sphere radius
\def\ch{3.75} % cone height
\def\ph{30}   % phi angle
\def\th{80}   % theta angle, 45<th<90

% isometric axes
\pgfmathsetmacro\xx{1/sqrt(2)}
\pgfmathsetmacro\xy{1/sqrt(6)}
\pgfmathsetmacro\zz{sqrt(2/3)}

\pgfmathsetmacro\cr{\ch*tan(\ph)} % cone radius
\pgfmathsetmacro\cg{\ch/cos(\ph)} % cone generatrix
\pgfmathsetmacro\ih{\sr*cos(\ph)} % intersection circle (sphere-cone) height
\pgfmathsetmacro\ir{\sr*sin(\ph)} % intersection circle (sphere-cone) radius

\pgfmathsetmacro\gs{sqrt((2*\ch*\ch-\cr*\cr)/(3*\cr*\cr))} % generatrix slope
\pgfmathsetmacro\xt{sqrt(6)*\gs*\ch/(1+3*\gs*\gs)}         % tangent point x
\pgfmathsetmacro\yt{\gs*\xt}                               % tangent point y
\pgfmathsetmacro\aa{(\ch*\zz-\yt)/\xy/2-\xt/\xx/2}         % coordinate x in xy plane
\pgfmathsetmacro\bb{(\ch*\zz-\yt)/\xy/2+\xt/\xx/2}         % coordinate y in xy plane
\pgfmathsetmacro\at{atan(\bb/\aa)+180}                     % angle to the tangent point

% ellipse in the greeen plane
\pgfmathsetmacro\xq{(sin(\th)+cos(\th))*\xx}    % Q(xq,yq), point in the minor axis (2d coordinates)
\pgfmathsetmacro\yq{(sin(\th)-cos(\th))*\xy}
\pgfmathsetmacro\aq{-atan(\xq/\yq)}             % angle between OQ and the horizontal (2d)
\pgfmathsetmacro\xr{sqrt(2)*\xq)/(-1+tan(\th))} % R(xr,yr,zr), point Q in isometric coordinates (3d)
\pgfmathsetmacro\yr{\xr*tan(\th)}
\pgfmathsetmacro\zr{(\xr+\yr+\yq*sqrt(6))/2}
\pgfmathsetmacro\ar{90-atan(\zr/sqrt(\xr*\xr+\yr*\yr))} % angle between OQ and the horizontal (3d)


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,x={(-\xx cm,-\xy cm)},y={(\xx cm,-\xy cm)},z={(0cm,\zz cm)}]
% sphere
\begin{scope}
  \draw[sphere_outside] (0,0) circle (\sr cm);
\end{scope}
% cone (inside)
  \draw[cone_inside] ($(90-\at:\ir)+(0,0,\ih)$)   arc (90-\at:-360+\at:\ir) --
                     ($(-360+\at:\cr)+(0,0,\ch)$) arc (-360+\at:90-\at:\cr) -- cycle;
\begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z=\ch]
  \draw[] (0,0) circle (\cr);
\end{scope}
% cone (ouside west)
  \draw[cone_outside] ($(\th:\ir)+(0,0,\ih)$) arc (\th:\at:\ir) --
                      ($(\at:\cr)+(0,0,\ch)$) arc (\at:\th:\cr) -- cycle;
% y axis
\draw[thick,-latex] (0,\sr,0) -- (0,\sr+2,0) node[right] {$y$};
% sphere (inside)
\draw[sphere_inside]
  {[canvas is xy plane at z=0] (\th:\sr) arc (\th:0:\sr)}
  {[canvas is xz plane at y=0] arc (0:90:\sr)}
  {[rotate around z=\th, canvas is xz plane at y=0] arc(90:0:\sr)};
\begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z=0]
  \draw[blue,-latex] (0.5*\sr,0) arc (0:\th:0.5*\sr)
     node[midway,below] {$\theta_0$};
\end{scope}
% plane
\draw[plane]
   {[rotate around z=\th, canvas is xz plane at y=0]
     (0,\ch) -- (0,0) -- (\sr,0) arc (0:-\ar:\sr)}
   {[x={(1 cm, 0 cm)}, y={(0 cm, 1cm)}] arc (\aq:-90:\sr)}
   {[rotate around z=\th, canvas is xz plane at y=0] --
     (0,-0.75*\ch) -- (\ch,-0.75*\ch) -- (\ch,\ch) -- cycle};
\begin{scope}[rotate around z=\th, canvas is xz plane at y=0]
  \draw[blue,-latex] (0,1.5*\sr) arc (90:90-\ph:1.5*\sr)
     node[midway,above] {$\varphi_0$};
\end{scope}
% z axis
\draw[thick,-latex] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,\ch+1) node[left]  {$z$};
% cone (ouside east)
\draw[cone_outside] (0,0,0) -- ($(\ir,0)+(0,0,\ih)$) arc (0:90-\at:\ir) --
                    ($(90-\at:\cr)+(0,0,\ch)$) arc (90-\at:\th:\cr) -- cycle;
% x axis
\draw[thick,-latex] (0,0,0) -- (\sr+2,0,0) node[left]  {$x$};
% red lines in the plane
\begin{scope}[rotate around z=\th, canvas is xz plane at y=0]
  \draw[thick,red] (90-\ph:\cg) -- (0,0) -- (\ch,0);
\end{scope}
\fill[red] ($(\th:\ir)+(0,0,\ih)$) circle (0.35mm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And this is my drawing:
[image]
**Update:** I joined some paths, removed a "cheating" clip (in exchange for more trigonometry), and fixed the visibility.

Comment: Excellent! That is very beautiful! Thanks for your complete answer.